# Using CSS, how to modify a child element by its class without impacting another child element with the same class but slightly different parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Using CSS, how to modify a child element by its class without impacting another child element with the same class but slightly different parent.

For example, in my example below:

```
<div class="PQR">
    <div class="ABC>
      <div class = "XYZ"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="DEF ABC">
      <div class = "XYZ"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My requirement is that I want to reduce the width by 50% of only first XYZ without impacting the other XYZ

The below statement impacts both the sections as both XYZ class have at least one of their parent class as ABC.

`.ABC .XYZ{width:50%}`

I tried the below 2 options but they did not work:

```
.ABC .XYZ:not(.DEF > .XYZ) {
  width: 50%
}

.ABC .XYZ:not(.DEF .XYZ) {
  width: 50%
}
```

Comment: Will it always be the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ABC:not(.DEF) .XYZ {
  width: 50%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your html(you missed `"`) and you can select `ABC` which doesn't have `DEF`.

```css
.XYZ {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.ABC:not(.DEF) .XYZ {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="PQR">
  <div class="ABC">
    <div class="XYZ">Preant "ABC"</div>
  </div>

  <div class="DEF ABC">
    <div class="XYZ">Preant "DEF ABC"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or you can override by using the second parent

```css
.XYZ {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.DEF .XYZ {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="PQR">
  <div class="ABC">
    <div class="XYZ">Preant "ABC"</div>
  </div>

  <div class="DEF ABC">
    <div class="XYZ">Preant "DEF ABC"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```